# Generating menu based on user role Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 different roles (administrator and regular user); based on the user that was entered only those menus they'll have access to. However, I'm not sure how to get the menu from such. Their roles are stored in a database table. This is what I have so far in the design window.

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DynamicHoverStyle-BackColor="#99ccff" Orientation="Horizontal" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="#003366" DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" ScrollDownImageUrl="~/Img/1.jpg" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" >
    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#99CCFF" />
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Home/Welcome.aspx" Text="Home" Value="Home" ToolTip="Home" ></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem  Text="Search User"  ToolTip="Search"></asp:MenuItem>

        <asp:MenuItem Text="Add User" Value="Add User">

        <asp:MenuItem  NavigateUrl="~/Account/login.aspx" Text="Log Out"  ToolTip="Log Out"></asp:MenuItem> 
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Update

```
if (dr.Read())
{
    if (Convert.ToString(dr["RoleName"]) == "Administrator")
    {
        Menu1.Items.Add(new MenuItem
        {
            NavigateUrl = "~/Home/Welcome.aspx",
            Text = "Home",
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418821/how-to-show-some-part-of-aspx-page-based-on-a-login-user-roles

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447849/add-items-to-menu-dynamically-in-asp-net-website

Answer (score 1):

1. Add IDs to your menu items giving them distinct names. Set `visible='false'` on the admin items
2. In your codebehind file check if the user is an admin. If so, set `visible=true` on the admin items.

Depending on your requirement, you could disable them (in which case they'd appear in the menu but not work unless the user was an admin).

Menu item:
`<asp:MenuItem ID="menu1" visible="false" Text="Add User" Value="Add User">`

Codebehind would be along the lines of:

`if (user.isAdmin) 
{
menu1.Visible = true
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Session**. Check if he is **admin** then show his menu and if he is **regular user** then show his menu.

```
if(Session["type"]=="admin")
{
//
}
else if(Session["type"]=="regularUser")
{
//
}
```

Comment: would have to pull the type from the database

Comment: Yes, you need to if so

Comment: so how the menu comes in play after the session

Comment: According to your expectation, You just need to understand if else structure. What you need to show or not that's totally up to.

Comment: do understand that structure but is when it comes to the navigation section.

Comment: @Jane Check out Tim's answer below. Let us know if you need further help

Comment: is it possible to store menu in a session so that it be used on different pages